# Using Taylor to prove an inequality.

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, taylor-expansion

I have the function $f: (0,1)^2 \to (0,+\infty)$ with type $$f(x,y) = x \log\left(\frac{x}{y}\right) + (1-x) \log\left(\frac{1-x}{1-y}\right)$$

I would like to get an upper bound for f(x,y) in terms of $|x-y|$.

I have the following idea. To simplify notation fix $y$ and  let $g(x) = f(x,y)$.
We have $$ g'(x) = - \log(\frac{1-x}{1-y}) + \log(\frac{x}{y})$$ and
$$g''(x) = \frac{1}{1-x} + \frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{(1-x)x}$$.

If $x < y$ using Taylor in the interval $[x,y]$ we have for a $\xi \in [x,y]$

$$ g(x) = g(y) + g'(y)(y-x) + g''(\xi) (y-x)^2/2 = g''(\xi) (x-y)^2/2. $$

If $x> y$ the using Taylor in the interval $[y,x]$ we get the same
expression as above.
Since $g''(x)$ is convex and is minimized at $x_0 = 1/2$ we have that
if $|x-1/2| < |y-1/2|$ then $g''(\xi) \leq g''(y)$ else $g''(\xi) \leq g''(x)$.

Therefore,
$$
g(x) = f(x,y) \leq \max(g''(x), g''(y))(x-y)^2/2 \leq  (g''(x) + g''(y)) (x-y)^2/2
$$

**Question**
Is the above proof correct? In particular I am not sure whether I can use
Taylor in the closed interval $[x,y]$ or $[y,x]$.

Comment: The last part of your argument is really hard to follow.  Where did the expression $(g''(x) + g''(y)) (x-y)^2/2$ come from, for instance?

Comment: I edited my question, is it more clear now ?

Comment: What happened to the first two terms in $g(x)$?  Also, I don't believe your claims about comparing $g''(\xi)$ to $g''(x)$ and $g''(y)$: what if $x$ and $y$ are on opposite sides of $1/2$?

Comment: $g(y) = g'(y) = 0$. I think that since $g''(\xi)$ is minimum for $\xi =1/2$ and maximized at the point that is furthest from $1/2$ my arguments are correct...

Comment: Ah, OK, I see.  I think this works then.

Comment: @EricWofsey Thanks, for pointing out the missing details. My main concern is about the interval $[x,y]$ and the usual conditions of differentiability etc. of Taylor.